# How to use Google Speech API in an end user c# application securely after Authenticating them with Firebase Auth?

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

**Background on my login flow:**

I'm creating a C# WPF *Application* which will be distributed to an end-user.

On my *Website*, I'm using FirebaseUI Auth to do the login authentication so that the user can log in with Google, Facebook or Email.

When the user initiates a log into the *Application*, it transfers the user over to the *Website* temporarily which mints a custom JWT token on the server which is returned to the *Website* then ->  *Application* and then *Application* then uses to the freshly minted JWT token to Authenticate with [FirebaseAuthentication.net](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet) to generate a Firebase auth token. This works great for connecting to Firebase REST API's like Firestore to obtain user information on client *Application*.

**The Problem:** 
Not only do I want to connect to the Firebase API's, but to the Google Cloud Speech API as well (in this case Speech-To-Text). I don't believe the Firebase auth token is sufficient to achieve this. I can verify the user and access their Firebase data on the server or the client, yet this is insufficient to connect to the Google Speech-To-Text API. In Google's examples using the client credentials first requires obtaining an auth-code from their authorization endpoint. In [Google's Windows Application OAuth Example](https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/blob/e79f1575b5858c5f617d29f2435a93996e4248c5/OAuthDesktopApp/OAuthDesktopApp/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L37) This is the https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth authorization endpoint. [image: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/]

**Theorizing creates another potential question which could sooner answer the question:**
Could I use my FirebaseUI Auth page as an OAuth Endpoint to somehow authenticate my End-User Application with Google to connect to the Google Speech-to-Text API instead of using the https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth endpoint?

**The Question:**
How do I access the Google Cloud Speech-To-Text API from an end-user Application after authenticating them with Firebase Auth?

Google's reference for how to authenticate as an end-user:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud Speech API auth needs to happen separately. You would need to enable this API from Cloud Console and create the [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) key. Since this is an end user app I would recommend doing it on the server side. API integration examples are available in the [Firebase GCP Integration Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration).

Comment: I will definitely take a look at this!

Comment: yes I'll definitely accept your answer if it works it might take a couple days though because this is quite extensive to test & look through and implement!

Comment: Wouldn't this be unsafe since if the project is decompiled couldn't the user obtain unlimited access? Is there a way to dictate how much each user can use the API?

Comment: would it be safe to send a service account key to an end-user application at all?

Comment: That's why I am recommending it to do on the server side. Service accounts are not meant for end users.

Comment: After I authenticate the user on the server side, I still need to somehow initiate a connection between the user and the speech api on the client-side to start transmitting and receiving data from gcp. How would that be done? don't I need to then send something back to the user after I have authenticated them so that they can connect to the apis? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Your users don't need to interact with the api directly. Take data from the end user run the api on server and return the results. You will be writing a custom service that does all this.

Comment: Wouldn't that require me to stream a ton of audio streams to my server before streaming them to gcp? Is it impossible without the middle step of streaming it to my server?

Comment: Another option is you could generate [jwt token](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication) on the server and hand it over to client to make the request.  But you need to make sure that you account for renewal/generation of jwt tokens. They expire in one hour.